# Add space between tableviewcell and tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**What's the proper way to set left an right margins for a tableviewcell within a tableview?**

Here's an image of what Im going for:

[image]

And here's what I actually have:
[image]

I can get the spacing on the left, but not on the right. I've set the contentInsent to this:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
```

but it's not working either. Instead it's allowing a horizontal scroll on the tableview.

Comment: What if you change `right: 16` to `right: -16`?

Comment: Tried that and it's not working either. Although I feel like it should @matt

Comment: Yeah, I think we're going at this the wrong way. Adding an answer about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I wanted to achieve the interface you're showing, this would have nothing to do with the table view insets. I would *draw the cells* to have that appearance. This would be a matter of the cell's background view. Each cell would fill the space, as intended, but the cell would *draw* an inner rounded rect within itself.